# Problem with the interrogative forms when HERE IS/ARE is positioned at the beginning

Tags: sentence-construction

If a sentence is made with HERE IS/ARE at the start, what can be the possible interrogative form? For example:
Here is your pen.
Is here your pen?
Or any separate sentence:
Is here anyone to help me out in making database through MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

Both examples could have different answers, depending on what you mean.

For your first example, the interrogative "where" might fit:
**Where is your pen.**
or you might mean
**Is your pen here?**
or
**Is this your pen?**

For the second example,

If you are asking whether someone who can help exists, you could say
**Is there anyone who can help me make a database in Access?**

If you are asking if there is anyone present who can help, you could say
**Is there anyone here who can help...?**

If you are asking for the  location of a person who can help, you could say either
**Where is there someone who can help...?**
or, more likely,
**Where can I find someone to help...?**